# Marklogic querying using XML string

Tags: marklogic

Hi all i am trying to get this to work using *CTS* queries and a user input **XML** string that conforms to a *CTS* query.

test.xqy:

```
let $query:=xdmp:unquote(xdmp:get-request-field('query'))
let $results:=cts:search(/,$query)
return
<r>
<q>
{$query}
</q>
{$results}
</r>
```

query will be

```
<cts:element-value-query>
  <cts:element>date</cts:element>
  <cts:text xml:lang="en">2013-11-18</cts:text>
</cts:element-value-query>
```

What i dont understand is how come there are always no results. Using 
replacing **$query** with

```
let $query:=cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("date"),"2013-11-18")
```

always works.

So i dont understand whats the difference between a custom xml string converted with `xdmp:unquote` is any different from a `cts:element-value-query`. I have printed both of them out and they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search takes a `cts:item` not an XML element. If `xdmp:get-request-field('query')` is expected to return serialized cts:query XML, try this:

```
`cts:query(xdmp:unquote(xdmp:get-request-field('query'))/*)`
```

The `/*` step is necessary because `xdmp:unquote` returns a document node.

Comment: Thanks mblakele seems we reached the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

unquoting the XML string will return an XML document, not a cts:query.  You might expect to get a type clash in that case, but I think that cts:search can also accept a string as a query, in which case the string is interpreted as a cts:word-query.  So I think what is happening is that the string value of your XML document ("date 2013-11-18", modulo white space) is being interpreted as a word-query, and not matching anything.

To do what you are trying to do, I think you may need to use xdmp:eval() - not unquote.  However I wouldn't really recommend allowing executable code to be passed in as a query parameter.  That just cries out for abuse.

Comment: Yeap u are right in that xdmp:unquote will not return me a cts:query object. I sort of found the answer and will post below.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason as Mike says is that xdmp:unquote will not give me a cts:query.

What is need is to actually use cts:query itself to convert element into cts:query
so after

```
let $query:=xdmp:unquote(xdmp:get-request-field('query'))
let $cts_query:=cts:query($query)
let $results:=cts:search(/,$cts_query/*)
```

U can find in under the search developers guide, Function to Construct a cts:query From XML